# React js - working with textbox values and c#

Tags: c#, reactjs, textbox

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var author = this.refs.author.value;
        var text = this.refs.text.value;

        if (!text || !author){
            return;
        }

        this.props.onCommentSubmit({Author:author, Text:text});
        this.refs.author.value = '';
        this.refs.text.value = '';
        return;
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="author"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Say something" ref="text" />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" />
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

ABOVE CODE WORKS FINE. BUT A LOT OF PPL SAY NOT TO USE REFS. SO I TRIED THIS BUT HAVE TWO PROBLEMS.

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();       

        var form = e.target;
        var author = form.querySelector('[name="author"]');
        var text = form.querySelector('[name="text"]');

        if (!text || !author){
            return;
        }

        this.props.onCommentSubmit({Author:author, Text:text});

        // HOW TO BLANK OUT THE AUTHOR AND TEXT FIELDS ??? 

        return;
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="author"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Say something" name="text" />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" />
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

TWO ISSUES:
1) HOW DO I BLANK OUT THE TWO TEXT INPUT FIELDS SINCE I NO LONGER HAVE A REF?

2) WHEN IT SUBMITS TO THE C# CONTROLLER, THE VALUES (E.G., "Jack Smith", "This is text" both get converted to the literal "[object HTMLInputElement]". Something gets lost in the translation.

```
handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('Author', comment.Author);
        data.append('Text', comment.Text);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', this.props.submitUrl, true);
        xhr.onload=function() {
            this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send(data);
```

THE AUTHOR AND TEXT VALUES ARE CORRECT AT THIS POINT. BUT UPON "xhr.send(data)", WHEN IT HITS THE C# API CONTROLLER METHOD, THE VALUES HAVE BEEN CONVERTED TO THE LITERAL "[object HTMLInputElement]".

IF YOU HAVE READ THIS FAR, THANK YOU ... ;-)

Comment: Please edit your post to remove your all-caps text.

Comment: lol, I did it to "try" and make it more readable. i'll leave as is, but will not do so in future posts. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both issues address the same problem. You have to use the `value` attribute of the `input` and not the DOM Node itself.

So what you should do is:

```
this.props.onCommentSubmit({Author: author.value, Text: text.value});
```

Also you can clear the input afterwards by overriding this value again:

```
author.value = '';
text.value = '';
```

In my view, the better and more react way is to use controlled inputs. Define state variables `author` and `text` and bind them with an `onChange` function. This way you can also do some validation during input.

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/oxak1azv/2/

And also https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: it works, muchos gracias. also, i will refactor to use controlled inputs. thanks !